# path is required in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, reactjs, express

**model(Product.js)**
[image]

route(product.js)
[image]

> product validation failed: oem: Path `oem` is required.,
>
> category: Path `category` is required.,
>
> sub_category: Path `sub_category` is required.,
>
> model_no: Path `model_no` is required.",

Comment: `Console.log(req.body)` and post that result here in the question to debug the code

Comment: Just post the code on stackoverflow, no need for screenshoots

Comment: Hint: never ever put screen shots up for something that is text. Whoever told you to replace your text code input with screenshots: wrong idea.

Comment: Got  it thankyou  for the advice @GhostCat I'm new here so I dont know much

Comment: I know, that is why I am telling to give you clear messages what you could do differently ;-)

Comment: yes now I understand : ) thank you once again

Answer (score 1):

```
const requiredFields = ["oem", "category", "sub_category", "model_no"];
const isPayloadInvalid = requiredFields.some(el => !req.body[el]);
if (isPayloadInvalid) return res.status(400).json({ error: "missing required fields" });
```

Just add this before before line `14`.

But that is just me that wanted to use `Array.prototype.some()`, just catch `mongoose.Error.ValidationError` and send `HTTP 400` notifying that some params are missing.

Comment: Guys I'm trying hard out here just following your codes

Comment: I have added another question just for clarification of code can you please help out?

Comment: @BakorKharkongor where?

Comment: here just follow the link https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/20806679 Sorry new user and also new to restfulapi @Sid

Answer (score 0):

It seems the POST body is not carrying all the required elements.